# "Bulk Collect Into" and "Execute Immediate" in Oracle

Tags: oracle

is it possible to execute the `"bulk Collect into"` with the `"execute immediate"` commands in oracle? All of that would be part of a function that returns a pipe lined table as a result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, technically you can:

```
  1  SQL> declare
  2   type x is table of t.id%type index by pls_integer;
  3   xx x;
  4  begin
  5   execute immediate
  6   'select id from t' bulk collect into xx;
  7   dbms_output.put_line(xx.count);
  8  end;
  9  /
426
```

And Oracle clearly states this in the documentation:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/executeimmediate_statement.htm

But you can use more useful way event if you really NEED to execute Dynamic SQL - weak ref cursors. You will have the access to such powerful option as LIMIT and will be able to use collections of records.

```
SQL> declare
  2   type x is table of t%rowtype index by pls_integer;
  3   xx x;
  4   c sys_refcursor;
  5  begin
  6    open c for 'select * from t';
  7    loop
  8      fetch c bulk collect into xx limit 100;
  9      dbms_output.put_line(xx.count);
 10      exit when c%notfound;
 11    end loop;
 12    close c;
 13  end;
 14  /
100                                                                             
100                                                                             
100                                                                             
100                                                                             
26
```

Comment: I really need to use dynamic sql, so you think using refcursors is a better idea than unsing bulk collect?

Comment: Yes, ref cursor is a relevant solution if you are going to proceed a large batch of rows. LIMIT allows you to get portion of record step-by-step instead of pumping all volume in PGA at once.

Comment: It's an old question, but a popular one, and still valid in Oracle 18. I would like to point out that @DmitryNikiforov says _more useful way_ because you do not want `execute immediate '..' bulk collect into xx` in your code except if you are sure that the number of records will always be reasonable small.  Otherwise, it will work until one day the amount of records is too large.

Answer (score 1):

Following the idea proposed by Dmitry Nikiforov I solved the problem using cursors and here is the solution ;)

```
FUNCTION myFunction (  parameter_p IN VARCHAR2) RETURN myTableType PIPELINED

IS
  c sys_refcursor;
  stmt varchar2(4000);  
  out_rec mYrowType;
  rec mYrowType;
BEGIN

    stmt:='Select * from ''' || parameter_p || '''';
    open c for stmt;

    LOOP
    fetch c into rec;
    EXIT WHEN c%NOTFOUND;

        out_rec.field1 := rec.field1;
        out_rec.field2 := rec.field2;
        out_rec.field3 := rec.field3;

        PIPE Row(out_rec);
    END LOOP;

  Close c;
  Return;

END myFunction;
```