# How can I use table name as a variable in nested for loops in oracle pl/sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, variables, for-loop

I have a query like this:

```
 v_sql:= 'select count(1) from '||v_tbl||' where col1 = ' || month_var || ' and ds =''T''';
 execute immediate v_sql into v_row_cnt;

   for j in 1..v_row_cnt
    loop
      for i in (select b.* from
               (select a.*, rownum as rn
                from (select * from MY_TABLE where col1 = month_var and DS = 'T') a
                 ) b
               where rn=j)
      loop

          do_something;
      end loop;
     end loop;
```

Now, my problem is, I can't hard code MY_TABLE here. I need to use a variable. I am currently doing it this way because I need to process data row by row.

Any ideas how to do this?

Thanks.
Ronn

Comment: Why you don't open for loop directly with constructed SQL string?

Comment: E.g. look at second variant in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21117326/232279) and implement it without `bulk collect`.

Comment: still having problem to understand .. because I have two for loops here which are nested. How can I implement this with ref cursor?

Comment: You have only 1 iteration in your internal loop because of 'where rn=j' condition. So it may be removed.

Comment: how? v_row_count can have value > 1. I have multiple rows in v_tbl.

Comment: Ok, it's a different tables. But how first query linked with loop? Just by row count?

Comment: actually what I am doing here is - get the row count from v_tbl, and then run the for loops on MY_TABLE that many times (row count). the 'do_something' is processing row wise data from MY_TABLE.

Comment: @user3197733 just do another `execute immediate` or `open cursor for query_string` inside your loop

Answer (score 2):

You would use [dynamic SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#LNPLS011) to build a cursor.

There is an inefficiency in your logic here: you start by counting the number of rows in a given table, then you execute the same query once for each row (another example of [Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter%27s_algorithm)).

You don't need to do that, just **loop over the cursor**, this will execute the query once only. For example:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     l_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
  3     l_table VARCHAR2(32) := 'ALL_OBJECTS';
  4     l_name VARCHAR2(32);
  5  BEGIN
  6     OPEN l_cursor FOR 'SELECT object_name
  7                          FROM ' || l_table
  8                    || ' WHERE rownum <= 5 ';
  9     LOOP
 10        FETCH l_cursor INTO l_name;
 11        EXIT WHEN l_cursor%NOTFOUND;
 12        -- do_something
 13        dbms_output.put_line(l_name);
 14     END LOOP;
 15     CLOSE l_cursor;
 16  END;
 17  /

C_OBJ#
I_OBJ#
TAB$
CLU$
C_TS#
```

You don't need to count the number of rows beforehand, if the cursor is empty the loop with exit immediately.

Comment: Cool.. But for a `CLOSE l_cursor` finally.!

Comment: thanks .. but I need to process the data of MY_TABLE row by row. for example, results of one row may need to override the output of one column (not all) calculated from the previous row.. I hope you understand :(

Comment: @user3197733 it looks like you're querying a table for just one row over and over again. This looks wrong, as a single cursor wound be more efficient. Still, if you can't simplify your algorithm, at least you can make it work with dynamic cursors as shown in my answer. Good luck =)