# Bulk Collection with dynamic sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I have a requirement where I get the table name and column name dynamically, I need to fetch the data and insert/ update in a table using bulk collect. As far as I checked I will not be able to use FORALL for dynamic sql which use dynamic table/column name. Please suggest any workaround to insert the data in a collection by bulk

```
Declare 
   Type Type_xx is table of varchar2(200);

   Lv_Coll  type_xx:=type_xx();
   Lv_Coll2   sys_refcursor;
   Lv_tab   varchar2(200):='C_Sample_1';
   Lv_Col   Varchar2(200):='SHORT_NAME';
   Out_tab  Varchar2(200):='Test';

Begin
   OPEN Lv_Coll2 FOR  'Select '||Lv_Col||' from '||Lv_tab||'';
        Loop
            Fetch Lv_Coll2 bulk collect into Lv_Coll limit 100;
            Exit when Lv_Coll.count < 100;
            forall i in Lv_Coll.first..Lv_Coll.last 
                Execute Immediate 'insert into '||Out_tab||' values ('||Lv_Coll(i)||')';
           End loop;
end;
```

It gives the error

> ORA-06550: line 16, column 17:
>   PLS-00801: internal error [*** ASSERT
>   at file pdw4.c, line  620; Unknown expression Expr = 283.;
>   Xanon__0x2b21bbdd8__AB[16, 17]]

Database version is 11.2.0.4.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Bulk Collect Into" and "Execute Immediate" in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117021/bulk-collect-into-and-execute-immediate-in-oracle)

Comment: @Rene I am able to fetch data in bulk but unable to insert in bulk.

Comment: According to this that's not possible.
https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9531830000346274113

Comment: Why do you want to use `BULK COLLECT`? You'll not have any significant improvements in performance using it over a single update/insert ( dynamic or otherwise )

Comment: @KaushikNayak it is not doing the single update and I wanted to do it in bulk, my challenge is it is a dynamic sql

Comment: It should definitely be possible to cleverly rewrite them to implement it purely through update statements, as minimal as one might want and without using any bulk DMLs

Comment: So which bit needs to be dynamic? The *"fetch the data"* bit? The *"insert/ update"* bit? The target table? You've got a bunch of people trying to figure out what you want to do. Please **edit your question** to make your requirement clearer.

Comment: My requirement is to form a SQL query dynamically, I will not know the column name/table name until the procedure receives the input and insert or update(Depends on the place) to a table. So to handle large volume forall is not supporting execute immediate.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not a preferred solution, but you can put your whole bulk insert PL/SQL block inside an EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do that :

```
declare
 type t_ntt is table of test1%rowtype index by pls_integer;
 l_ntt t_ntt;
 c_limit INTEGER := 100;
 sqltext VARCHAR2(1000);
 table_name VARCHAR2(30) := 'test1';
 column_name VARCHAR2(30) := 'A';
 c_cursor sys_refcursor; 
begin
  open c_cursor for 'select '|| column_name|| ' from ' || table_name ;
  loop
    fetch c_cursor bulk collect into l_ntt limit c_limit;
    exit when l_ntt.count = 0;
    dbms_output.put_line(l_ntt.count);
    forall i in indices of l_ntt
    insert into test values l_ntt(i);

  end loop;
  close c_cursor;

end;
```

I have not done the commit on it.

Comment: Thank you, I want something like this, but the above code gives me an error stating too many values when I run as it is. I specified the column name in the insert statement and it says unimplemented features.

Comment: Hi Ashokkumar, it will be better if you can provide a glimpse of your code with the error, simply asking won't help us see what you exactly want.
the above code that I provided you is working fine in my system.